# Bootstrap aligning grids

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am new to bootstrap and would like to be aliging elements in my grids.

At http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment they explain how to align only text and only the text contained inside the (p) tag. I was neither able to reproduce this with other elements such as buttons, nor with text in a simple (label) tag.

Is this feature more flexible? This seems like a really convenient and widely used feature it would be a pity if it only worked with text inside a (p) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css class inside any div using bootstrap to align any element,
 e.g `<div class="col-md-12 text-center">I'm center aligned</div>`

Comment: the example is there, another example `<div class="row">      <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><label>I'm in center</label></div></div>`

Comment: or you can also do it like this `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><label class="text-center">I'm in center</label></div></div>`

Comment: Ok that does seem to be working. Now do you know if I can do it on specific elements inside a col, without making a nested col?

Comment: I tried it out and yes you can as long as they are wrapped in a div, now one last question. Does it only work with div tags?

Comment: Ok I was just waiting for you to answer my other questions. Because most people don't bother answering the comments when they get the best answer. Most people are just in it for the points man, I hope your not.

Comment: Got alot of help from stack comunity in past, so just trying to return the favor n sharing what I learnt the hard way.